# Android camera intent timestamp is incorrect

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, timestamp

I have a code that calls the camera intent from android device to take picture, after that it will return to the previous activity with the taken picture. Everything works fine, but the problem is the timestamp (when check the photo details from gallery) of the photo is created in 1969. I have no idea why that happens

```
    Uri mCapturedImageURI;

    public void onClick(View v) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO);
    }
```

Comment: How are you reading the timestamp?

Comment: Which camera app are you using? Are you using a real device or an emulator? This might sound silly, but check the date on the device

Comment: I use the device's camera, the date on device is fine. However the details of photo on the emulator is correct but not on the real devices (I tested with 3 different real devices)

Comment: can you post your logcat report?

Comment: How do you know this timestamp is in 1969? What is the code that's showing you this?

Comment: @Teo I checked it from the photo's details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are using a real device for testing, please check the `Time` and the `Date` from the device settings manually.

IF you are using a `Android Virtual Device`, most probably it will be using you PC time. So make sure your PC time is correct.

**Hint:** try to modify the image after creation by writing an extra Character at the end (will not affect the image) and see the Last modification date, if it also since 1969, then the problem is on of the above

Comment: If I use the camera app directly, the date is fine. But when use it from my app, the date is wrong (1969). However the date from emulator seems to be correct, this issue only happens on real devices (I tested with many different devices already)

Comment: Does you app do this only with images, or with creating any kind of files?

Comment: I just checked the draw feature from my app, the saved image got the wrong date too, what's the issue?

Comment: From the above code, I can`t figure out any problem unless you are doing any extra steps out this scoop

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue, then I found the solution.

First I have placed the below code before calling `android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` like you

```
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

then the problem started.

Then, I placed the code inside `onActivityResult` callback my problem solved.

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
    this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);  
    startImageUpload(); // My upload process
    }
```